# What is the syntax of stored procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to do a simple inner join to select a row or even just get ID from inner join of 2 tables, one is the regular ASP.NET users table and the other one is mine (interpreters) somehow my syntax is not accessible -

http://pastebin.com/4aDPrtst

I think it expect something like

```
[Common].[tbl_Interpreter_Account].[AspNetUsers]
```

with all the `[][][][` but I am not sure

Comment: Can we start by asking "what is SQL Server 2013"? THe product does not exist.

Comment: I think SQL Server 2013 is express version of SQL Server which comes with VS 2013 :)

Comment: @marc_s I know what it would be :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: I assumed you knew :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `[Common]` is your database schema and `[AspNetUsers]` is the table automatically created using membership services (or by some other means), I'm unsure what `[tbl_Interpreter_Account]` refers to. Could you please clarify?

Also the join needs to be corrected.
You're joining what appears to be the following two tables: `AspNetUsers` and `AddIntrepeter`. But the join condition is on some other table `Interpreter_Account`

*Try the following:*

Insert your databasename at the top of the procedure.

```
USE [Common]

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetIntIdByEmail]
    @email  nvarchar(50)
AS
SELECT 
AspNetUsers.UserName
FROM [AspNetUsers] users 
INNER JOIN  [<<Your_Table>>] interpreter ON users.Id = interpreter.<<your_Matching_Column>>
WHERE interpreter.contact_email = @email
GO
```

Comment: SELECT 
AspNetUsers.Id
FROM [AspNetUsers] users  >>> where the users comes from?
INNER JOIN  [<<Your_Table>>] interpreter ON users.Id = Interpreter_Account.AspNetUserId
WHERE Interpreter_Acount_email = @email

Comment: thank you pkamathk. that is the first time I use this forum I left asp.net 4 years ago on asp.net 2 and now doing a project on .net 4

Comment: Thanks to all of you. the code that finally worked was: http://pastebin.com/xd6hgjGY